# How is this standard error obtained?

Tags: r, r-squared, caret, partial-least-squares

I am working through the exercises in Kuhn and Johnson's "Applied Predictive Modelling" and cannot reproduce one of their results in the exercises.

Looking at 4.3 we have

> ... find the number of PLS components that yields the optimal $R^2$ value... PLS models with 1 through 10 components were each evaluated using five repeats of 10-fold cross validation and the results are presented in the following table

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
| Components | R^2 Mean | R^2 Std Err |
+------------+----------+-------------+
|          1 |    0.444 |      0.0272 |
|          2 |    0.500 |      0.0298 |
|          3 |    0.533 |      0.0302 |
|          4 |    0.545 |      0.0308 |
|          5 |    0.542 |      0.0322 |
|          6 |    0.537 |      0.0327 |
|          7 |    0.534 |      0.0333 |
|          8 |    0.534 |      0.0330 |
|          9 |    0.520 |      0.0326 |
|         10 |    0.507 |      0.0324 |
+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Per the data description in the chapter I created a very simple `R` script to try to replicate this:

```R
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data("ChemicalManufacturingProcess")
ChemicalManufacturingProcess

set.seed(123654)

Predictors <- ChemicalManufacturingProcess %>% select(-Yield)
Response <- ChemicalManufacturingProcess$Yield

x <- caret::train(Predictors,
                  Response,
                  method = "pls",
                  tuneLength = 10,
                  preProcess = c("knnImpute","pca"),
                  trControl = caret::trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                                  repeats = 5))
x$results
```

When I evaluate the data myself I get something like the following:

```
   ncomp     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE    RMSESD RsquaredSD     MAESD
1      1 1.488470 0.4190524 1.173600 0.4022404  0.1896830 0.2532679
2      2 1.726840 0.4808378 1.144642 1.1424386  0.2283920 0.3779299
3      3 1.404174 0.5353202 1.045618 0.5296764  0.1826652 0.2324128
4      4 1.573533 0.5290127 1.094332 1.0883979  0.2009387 0.3425702
5      5 1.696461 0.5227886 1.123747 1.4242226  0.2018295 0.4235511
6      6 1.697423 0.5200149 1.123065 1.4043091  0.2009682 0.4206742
7      7 1.714735 0.5198054 1.131975 1.4369148  0.2029846 0.4330632
8      8 1.702231 0.5189913 1.132093 1.3808142  0.2025921 0.4224796
9      9 1.688245 0.5178315 1.130107 1.3186939  0.2032273 0.4091566
10    10 1.686446 0.5166508 1.130573 1.3055448  0.2028643 0.4081955
```

The `Rsquared` output behaves similarly to the published table but nothing here is close to the std error column. I'm clearly missing something simple; what is it?

Comment: With 5 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation you have 50 observations of $R^2$.  (Incorrectly) assuming independence, the s.e. of the mean of the observed $R^2$ values would be ~ 1/7 of the values listed in the `RsquaredSD` column, which seems not too far off, so that would be my guessplanation, to coin a word.